# ghostscript command line - page per file when using pipe?

Tags: image, pdf, pipe, stdout, ghostscript

`gs.exe -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sOutputFile=- -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dFirstPage=3 
-dLastPage=3 -sDEVICE=jpeg -q -r300 a.pdf'`

to convert pdf to image.
I'm using the `-` sign to the OutputFile parameter to use a pipe, how can I extract multi-page pdf using this way?
If I specify `%03d` with an outputfile name, I get multiple images (what I want), but with pipe it is different so I dont know how it works..

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell if you choose a pipe as the output, then Ghostscript just dumps the raw data straight to the pipe.

So you get the file header, image data and trailer, then the next page is processed the file header sent to the pipe, the image data and the the file trailer. And so on.

What were you expecting ?

Comment: If I use this command with pdf that has just one page, I can save it as jpg (in python using pipe with subprocess module), and see the image. I'm looking for a way I can get multiple images from multiple page pdf,  maybe page by page or a better way

Comment: If you want to save the file, then just have Ghostscript write the file. What's the point of piping it to stdout and then writing it to a file ? As I said above, if you use a multi-page input, and use stdout, then Ghostscript just sends each image sequentially to stdout. Its up to you to figure out what to do with that stream of data. The easy way to get multiple images is to write each page to a separate file, so using %d and -sOutputFile. I really don't understand why doing that is a problem.

Comment: Because I dont want ghostscript to save the files. I want to pass the raw images data to python for further processing.  If the images are passed in sequence, how can I "seperate" them in python code?